# Converting VarChar-Date into Unix Timesamp in mySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Hello at StackOverflow,

I have a mySQL-Database with a column called `date` (varchar64) and need the values (i.e. `01.12.15`) converted into a timestamp value. So I'm looking for a update-set-query that will do the trick.

Something with `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('26.11.17', '%d.%m.%y'))`? I have no idea how to make a query with that. Can anyone help out?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: where is the problem with your proposal? All works as expected http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4bc753/2

Comment: Yes, but how can I update my column? I have no idea how the query should look like. Somehting like "Update 'date' SET..."?

Comment: To update in the same column without conditions?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/deca9/1

Comment: Thanks man! Thats what I was looking for!!!

Answer (score 0):

To get a timestamp by varchar: `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('01.12.15', '%d.%m.%y'));`
To get a varchar by timestamp: `GET_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp), '%d.%m.%y');`

Note that it's affected by your current timezone.
In addition, it's not a good approach to store time by varchar. It's a waste of space, and slower. If you want to store a timezone-neutral time just use `TIMESTAMP` type or `BIGINT` type. If you want to store a timezone-specific time just use `DATETIME` type.